# Adding file to super module that is inside a submodule

Tags: git, version-control, kohana, kohana-3

I ran into this issue last night. I have my app in git called MyApp and inside the modules folder I have a submodule called Emailq. The problem is that the module makes me create a config file inside its folder.

I want the supermodule to be able to keep track of that file, not the submodule.

Is that even possible?

I tried to force add the file and it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

In the superproject, the path to the submodule is a real object, one which contains the commit in the submodule that should be checked out. It's not a tree (it's called a *gitlink*), so you can't put any content inside of it.

You might be able to kludge something with a symlink; otherwise, you probably need to look into making the submodule able to refer to config files outside of itself.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I read, but I wanted to confirm. Problem is that in Kohana, all config files are inside the module itself. Not sure if that is a good idea now.